# Tic Tac Toe and Minimax AI

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, minimax

Here is my code for a basic Tic Tac Toe program (minus the actual game class and my tests).
I'm having trouble writing the actual minimax algorithm. It's hard for me to verify what's actually going on, but this code seems to return just a random move from the current state.

My thoughts are, I can't initialize the 'best' variable in minimax() because it gets overwritten each time the function is called... I'm really lost at this point.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this algorithm? I feel like I'm so close, but missing some key point or concept about recursion that will put this all together.

```
def makeMove(board, player, location):
    gridlist = list(board)
    gridlist[location] = player
    return ''.join(gridlist)

def printBoard(board):
    return board

def winner(board):
    for row in winning_combos:
        if (board[row[0]] is not ' ') and (equal([board[i] for i in row])):
            return board[row[0]]

def equal(row):
    return row == [row[0]] * 3

winning_combos = [
        [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]

def availableMoves(board):
    return [k for k, v in enumerate(board) if v == ' ']

def isComplete(board):
    if availableMoves(board) == []:
        return True
    elif winner(board):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def x_won(board):
    return winner(board) == 'x'

def o_won(board):
    return winner(board) == 'o'

def tied(board):
    return isComplete(board) and winner(board) is None

def get_enemy(player):
    if player == 'x':
        return 'o'
    else:
        return 'x'

def score(board):
    if x_won(board):
        return 10
    elif o_won(board):
        return -10
    elif tied(board):
        return 0


def determine(board, player):
    if isComplete(board):
        return score(board)
    best = 0
    for move in availableMoves(board):
        board = makeMove(board, player, move)
        val = determine(board, get_enemy(player))
        print val
        if val > best:
            best = val
    return best
```

Comment: Hmm, aren't you supposed to return the negative of the best? Because your best move is your opponent's worst move, know what I mean?

Comment: There is definitely a condition there that I'm missing, but I think I'm missing a few more steps in this algorithm first and I've been beating my head against it for a few days with no results.

Answer (score 1):

Your code example is missing 1 crutial part of the minimax algorithm. Youare doing the max part, but not the min part. You are asuming that both players would always play the move with the higher value. That is not true. The opponent will take the lower value. So modify you determine function to check who's turn it is. If it is the computer's turn, take the higher value like you have been doing. But if it is the opponent's turn, take the lower value like this:

```
if(value<best)
   best = val;
```

this should fix your problem.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, I actually had several things wrong with it, not the least of which was your comment. I ended up finishing the algorithm, which had to be separated into the algorithm itself and a wrapper for the first run.

https://github.com/mekhami/tictactoe/blob/master/ttt.py This has the updated algorithm and wrapper (minimax() and determine() respectively) and it works like a charm.